# BottomNavigationView not working on single click - has to be clicked twice

Tags: java, android

So I started a new project and implemented BottomNavigationView, I made a class helper, BottomNavigationViewHelper so that the buttons stay where they are supposed to, everything is working perfectly except that the buttons in the navigationview have to be clicked twice insted of working on single click. If I do a single click on the button it will just highlight it and then I have to click it again to access the class/xml.

This is the code for the Helper Class

```
 public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
            BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
            try {
                Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
                shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
                for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                    //noinspection RestrictedApi
                    item.setShiftingMode(false);
                    // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                    //noinspection RestrictedApi
                    item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
            }
        }
 public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationView view){
        view.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.ic_house:
                        Intent intent1=new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class); //ACTIVITY_NUM=0
                        context.startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_search:
                        Intent intent2=new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM=1
                        context.startActivity(intent2);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_circle:
                        Intent intent3=new Intent(context, PicActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM=2
                        context.startActivity(intent3);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_alert:
                        Intent intent4=new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM=3
                        context.startActivity(intent4);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_android:
                        Intent intent5=new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM=4
                        context.startActivity(intent5);
                        break;

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the profile class

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext= ProfileActivity.this;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM=4;
    private static final String TAG ="ProfileActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        setupToolbar();
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu=bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
    }

    private void setupToolbar(){

        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onMenuItemClick:clicked menu item: "+item);

                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.profileMenu:
                        Log.d(TAG,"onMenuItemClick: Navigating to profile preferences.");
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finaly the xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/teal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Be carrefull to register a SelectListener, and not a **Re**selectListener !

```
public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationView view){
        view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
```

Comment: Thank you, jacquarg. This tiny but HUGE mistakes are hard to track.

Comment: @DanOprean if it helped you, mark this as the right answer. It helped me as well